# What will be the positive and negative testcases for Q&As tab in product detail page in an ecommerce mobile app?

Tags: manual-testing, testcase, performance-testing, application-software-testing, mobile-testing

I am testing an e-commerce mobile app, and on the product detail page there are multiple tabs like: Description, Technical Details, Reviews, Q&As etc.

I need to test the Q&A (Question and Answer) section? what will be the positive and negative test cases?

My ones are

1. The asked question appears on top
2. The user is taken to login if not already, and taken back to the product detail screen
3. The answer pop us appear to answer
4. The date of the answer and name of the person who answer is visible
5. The all questions and answers are visible with a see more button on a separate screen

I need more testcases, pls help.

Comment: Welcome to the community. It would be helpful if you include a URL to the app or a list of requirements you are testing against. Maybe add the an image of the page? So far, you've only listed some positive test cases. What do you think are some negative test cases?

Answer (score 0):

What does the specification of the Q&A's tab say, regarding behavior/functionality?

That will give you the basic functional test cases. Other than that, some subjective user experience analysis based on customer usage will help you to QA it for a start.

I'd read over the specs etc and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the positive and negative test cases which may help you for testing the Q&A section on e-commerce applications:-

**Positive:**

1. The user would be able to View the Q&A Tab on the Product Detail page.
2. The user would be able to view all those Q& A sections which are relevant to the opened product detail page only.
3. Check the Tab action when there is no Q& A in the Tab of the Product.
4. Check the Tab action. If they implemented any kind of pagination(Which means it shows the listing of Q&A 10,20, ---so on)
5. Name of the answerer should be visible. Sometimes they have a tag like Name of the Customer, Certified customer, Seller, Prime customer or likewise).
6. To verify the User would be able to Post their questions in the Tab. It show some message of successful along with your asked question or likewise.
7. The user should come back to the Q&A listing after posting its question(Sometimes redirection or any kind of done button is also provided).
8. Enter the Question and check the character limit sometimes they provided like(1/100).

**Negative:**

1. Enter the questions and Do not submit the Same. Now swipe to the different tab and come back to the Q&A Tab again. That question should be cleared now or rest of the things will depend on client requirements as well.
   Leave the question field blank and click on the submit button(Check validation).
2. Enter the question which exceeds the limits of its character value and click on the submit button(It should give validation).
3. Copy the Image and try to add the same in the question field.
4. Copy the Table sheets(excel file) and try to add it the same in the question field.
5. Try to Check Q&A Tab for those products which are Out of Stock or No longer available on the website.

Apart from the above test cases, below are the few security-related test cases used by Security testing services in the IT industry, that may also help you to understand the same:-

1. The user would not be able to post the question without login into the application(Should redirect to the Login page).
2. Verify that Error Message does not contain malicious info so that hackers will use this information to hack web site.
3. Verify that the restricted page should not be accessible by user after the session timed out.
4. Try to Open the Website with the Bookmark page system. It should redirect properly.
5. Try to add the Q& A Accessibility through the Cross Platforms Simultaneously( Web and Mobile).